# What's the difference between * and .* in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, wildcard, glob

I saw the wildcard of `*` been used in some command like: `find *.jpg`, which means find any files ended with `.jpg`. However, in regular expressions, `.*` also means that 0 or more times for any character. So, what's the difference between them? When is `*` been used and when is `.*`?

Comment: You're referring to two different things. A wildcard in a file name search is not a regular expression, so its meaning is as you describe and unrelated to its use in a regex.

Comment: Then, when we use wildcard and when we use regex?

Comment: The shell uses wildcards in a limited form of regular expression also known as 'globbing'.  It uses `*` to mean zero or more of any character, `?` to mean any one character, and has basic character classes `[A-Za-z]` and negated character classes (`[!A-Za-z]`, but beware shells that think `!` means something hysterical — err, historical).  It is nowhere near as powerful a regex language as even the BRE (basic regular expressions) found in POSIX and base-level `grep`, let alone ERE (extended regular expressions) or PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regular expressions, `*` is the "zero or more" repetition marker.  `.` is the "any single character (with caveats)" expression.

In a `find` the `*` character is an "anything" wildcard and is not really a regular expression character.  The `?` is the "any single character" in search situations of this kind.

Answer (score 5):

Filename matching patterns (or *globs*) and regular expressions are two similar but different things.

For both of them, most characters simply match themselves, and certain special characters have special meanings which can be suppressed by preceding them with a backslash `\`.

In a filename matching pattern (as used by shells and the `find` command), `?` matches any single character and `*` matches zero or more arbitrary characters. A `.` (period) is not a special character; it just matches a literal `.` character.

In a regular expression (as used by `grep`, many text editors, and most commands that perform searches on text), `.` matches any single character and `*` denotes zero or more occurrences of whatever precedes it.

There's quite a bit more to it than that. Filename matching patterns have special rules for "hidden" files whose names start with `.`, and the syntax and rules can vary somewhat from one shell to another. Regular expressions also exist in several forms (`grep` vs. `egrep`, vs. Perl or PCRE, for example).