# linux grep "*.out" and ls *.out

Tags: linux, bash

In Bash, when you type `ls *.out`, it will output the list which ended with `.out`. Is this a regular expression?

If yes; when I `echo a.out > test` and then type `grep *.out test`, it outputs nothing.

Is `*` in the ls same `*` in the regex?

Comment: Check these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702202/what-are-the-differences-between-glob-style-pattern-and-regular-expression and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673427/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-regular-expressions

Comment: thanks, that sound my ally.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search in all files ending in `.out`, try `grep <string> *.out`.

You also may want to read up on [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to understand is that your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) is expanding program arguments (passed to `main` function of executed programs). Read Bash chapter about [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) (and [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)))

So you should not type `ls "*.out"` but just `ls *.out` then the `/bin/ls` program is started with the *expansion* of `*.out`. For example, if you have files `a.out`, `b.out`, `cc.out`, `a.c` the expansion of `*.out` (done by the shell) is `a.out` `b.out` `cc.out` so `/bin/ls` gets `"ls"` `"a.out"` `"b.out"` `"cc.out"` followed by `NULL` as its `char**argv` second argument to its `main`, with the first `int argc` argument being 4.

But `grep` indeed want some [*regular expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or "regexp". You generally want to quote it (to *avoid* the shell to try its expansion).

Answer (score 1):

It's the shell that expands the filename globs, so in both `ls *.out` and `grep *.out test` the shell fills the filenames to the command line, and the command itself only sees the resulting list of names. Assuming you have files called `foo.out` and `bar.out`, those commands would be equivalent to these:

```
ls bar.out foo.out
grep bar.out foo.out test
```

The first one asks `ls` to list the files, the second asks grep to look for the pattern `bar.out` in the files `foo.out` and `test`. The latter is probably not what you want, so quote the pattern for grep:

```
grep "*.out" test
```

Except that that is not really a valid regular expression. In filename globs, the asterisk `*` matches zero or more characters, in regular expression it matches zero or more of the previous item (character, character group or expression in parenthesis), but at the start of line there aren't any, so the expression makes little sense. Perl complains about that, `grep` and `sed` don't, but they also don't seem to match anything.

In regexes, the dot `.` means any character, so needs to be escaped to be taken literally. Also, grep finds matches anywhere in the line, so the leading `.*` (which would match any number of any characters) can be omitted. So this would look for lines containing the string `.out` in the file `test`:

```
grep "\.out" test
```

As we saw, the patterns used by Bash and the patterns (regular expressions) used by grep are not the same. See e.g. [Bash's manual for the pattern matches used in filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) and the [man page `regex(7)` for regular expressions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html). Also note that there are different dialects of regexes, which aren't fully compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

By default, grep looks for the exact expression, not a regular expression, but you can tell it to look for a regular expression by adding the `-E` flag.

So I think what you're looking for is `grep -E *.out test`, though a little bit of research on the net would've given you what you wanted ;)

Comment: thanks, but immediately-preceding * is nothing, what does the ' * ' is really match?

Comment: No, by default `grep` looks for a match to a basic regular expression (BRE), `grep -F` (or `fgrep`) looks for a fixed string, and `grep -E` (or `egrep`) looks for an extended regular expression. GNU grep's man page mentions the difference between those in brief: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html

Answer (score 0):

1. For grep command, * means 0 or more occurences of prev/preceding character or expression. So in your case `grep .out* test` would work as it will look for the occurrence of `.ou` followed by 0 or more occurrence of any character in the file test.
2. For ls command, `ls *.out` would mean list all the files/folders ending with their name as `.out`.

Comment: the regex `.out*` would look for `ou` following any character, e.g. `bout`, `sou` or `~ou` (it would also match any number of `t`'s after that, but with regular grep, it means little.)

Comment: Thanks ikkikachu! That makes much more sense. I'll edit my answer.